# iOS 7 - detect which textField is highlighted from another function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry but I've been working on this problem for the past few hours. I'm using the MLPAutocomplete Class for the autocomplete text field in my application. I have no problems implementing the library. For my case, however, I have four text fields and the [implementation that was described in the gitHub](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField) does not describe how to implement the library with multiple text fields. So in order to supply the correct array of strings to the text field that is currently in use was to check which of the four text fields is highlighted. Here is the function that provides the array for the autocomplete text field.

What I basically do is that in my `viewDidLoad` method, I initialize the four arrays for the four textviews and in the function below, `possiblecompleteionsForString`, what I do is I take Boolean values based on whether or not a text field is highlighted. Based on this, I then assign the proper array to the completions array (completions array is the one shown in the textfield). However, I noticed that this does not work 100% of the time. There are cases wherein my app shows a different array. For example, I have set a text for my `brandInput` textfield and I try to input for the `partInput` textField, what happens is that the log shows the following:

```
2014-02-28 16:57:51.295 Database[7352:3f03] brand input Status active
2014-02-28 16:57:52.154 Database[7352:3f03] brand input Status active
2014-02-28 16:57:57.463 Database[7352:3f03] part input Status active 
2014-02-28 16:57:57.465 Database[7352:3f03] brand input Status active
```

It managed to detect that the brandInput `textField` was active, then it also saw that I switched over to the `partInput` textField. However, for an unknown reason, it still went to `brandInput` as the active one, giving me a wrong array.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
 possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string
            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSMutableArray *completions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [completions removeAllObjects];

        BOOL partInputStatus = partInput.highlighted;
        BOOL brandInputStatus = brandInput.highlighted;
        BOOL barcodeInputStatus = barcodeInput.highlighted;
        BOOL itemNameInputStatus = itemNameInput.highlighted;

        if(partInputStatus){
            NSLog(@"part input Status active");
            completions = [self part];
        }

        if(brandInputStatus){
            NSLog(@"brand input Status active");
            completions = [self brand];
        }

        if(barcodeInputStatus){
            NSLog(@"barcode input Status active");
            completions = [self barcode];
        }

        if(itemNameInputStatus){
            NSLog(@"itemname input Status active");
            completions = [self itemName];
        }

        handler(completions);
    });
}
```

How do I do this? I don't think marking `brand` as inactive won't work because the `Boolean` variables get reinitialized at the start of the function.

Is there any other way to detect which textField is active? I have seen some solutions, however, those are the delegate functions and I don't think I can call them from my function.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work for your case: `BOOL partInputStatus = [partInput canResignFirstResponder];`

OR

`BOOL partInputStatus = [partInput isFirstResponder];` as suggested by Matthias

If the input field is focused (the user is currently editing it), it can resign it's first responder status (that is dismiss the keyboard and go to it's normal state).

Comment: why not `isFirstResponder`?

Comment: That could also work! Didn't come to my mind when answering. Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote and accept. The `isFirstResponder` worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Set tag of your autocompleteTextField.

As these are extended version of UITextField it will call `textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField` delegate. From there you can check which field is active.

For Example:

```
partInput.tag = 1;
brandInput.tag = 2;
barcodeInput.tag = 3;
itemNameInput.tag = 4;
```

And int textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        //partInput
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 2) {
        //brandInput
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 3) {
        //barcodeInput
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 4) {
        //ItemNameInput
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: or just compare directly `if (textField == partInput)`